# How to connect sharepoint application page into Sql server Programatically

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, fast-for-sharepoint

I want the coding for connecting application page to Sql.Plz help me

Comment: Please be more clear with your question, there is no need for any task to make a sql connection with sharepoint, please state what it is that you want to do and how you intend on going about it.

Answer (score 1):

An application page can run pretty much any code you like, in C# or VB (and probably F# too, since it's .NET).

I'd suggest you start looking at the [documentation for SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). You can find many, many tutorials for using these classes on Google.

Comment: Thank u so much.

Answer (score 1):

its not a good practice to directly interface between SharePoint and SQL server, you can look at an alternate option of web services which directly talks to SQL server and later integrate it on the application page

Comment: Can u plz give some example code